# Recommended Windows LaTeX editor, similar to Kile ?

Tags: editors, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

My Linux box has crashed, so I'm looking for an editor on Windows (should work on Win7) that is similar to Kile - could someone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer would be [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/).

Main features of Kile are:

- Compile, convert and view your document with one click. *(<kbd>F1</kbd> in Texmaker)*
- Auto-completion of (La)TeX commands *(<kbd>TAB</kbd> or dropdown list)*
- Templates and wizards make starting a new document very little work. *(I don't recall templates being present, but there are useful wizards for tables, figures, lists. You can create your own templates and then use the `New by copying an existing file` option)*
- Easy insertion of many standard tags and symbols and the option to define (an arbitrary number of) user defined tags. *(nice menus for symbols in texmaker)*
- Inverse and forward search: click in the DVI viewer and jump to the corresponding LaTeX line in the editor, or jump from the editor to the corresponding page in the viewer. *(present in texmaker)*
- Finding chapter or sections is very easy, Kile constructs a list of all the chapter etc. in your document. You can use the list to jump to the corresponding section. *(also available)*
- Collect documents that belong together into a project. *(I am not aware of that feature in texmaker)*
- Easy insertion of citations and references when using projects. *(I am not aware of that feature in texmaker)*
- Flexible and smart build system to compile your LaTeX documents.
- QuickPreview, preview a selected part of your document. *(available)*
- Easy access to various help sources.
- Advanced editing commands.

Texmaker is also multiplatform, so you can keep using it when you go back to Linux. [Texworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) is another fine editor. It has a more minimalistic approach, and might not be as good a fit to Kile.

For other choices see [a list of latex editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).