# Is there any version of Kile for Windows?

Tags: kile, ide

I am using **Kile** in ubuntu. Is there any version of **Kile**  for Windows ?
 If so please, give me a download link.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Kile on Windows is experimental. May be see the answer to [Recommended Windows LaTeX editor, similar to Kile ? (duplicate)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15286/15717)

Comment: Using [Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/) might have been an option, but it seems that [Kile is not supported on Cygwin](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Kile-on-Cygwin-td25600.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility to install Kile on windows.

The project is called [KileOnWindows](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/kile/index.php?title=KileOnWindows) and is available on SourceForge.
I tried it a while ago and would definitely NOT use it again since it requires a nearly full installation of KDE on your Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[KDE for Windows](http://windows.kde.org/) has Kile, although I don't know, in what version at the moment.